# Error in printing common elements of two linked lists

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to print common elements in two linked lists but my function is printing only the first element if it is common

```
  void common()
    {
```

//head and head1 are respectively the head pointers of first and second list

```
      node1 *ptr=head;
      node2 *ptr2=head1;
      while(ptr!=NULL||ptr2!=NULL)
      {
          while(ptr!=NULL&&ptr2!=NULL)
          {
         if(ptr->info==ptr2->info)
            {
             printf("Common Elements are-%d\n",ptr2->info);
             ptr2=ptr2->next;
            }
          }
      ptr=ptr->next;
      ptr2=head1;


     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the increment of `ptr2` node out of `if` condition.

Whether the value of `ptr2->info` matches that of `ptr->info` is **not** the deciding condition for *moving to the next node* in `ptr2`. So, you have to move to next node unconditionally.

Something like

```
while(ptr!=NULL&&ptr2!=NULL)
      {
     if(ptr->info==ptr2->info)
        {
         printf("Common Elements are-%d\n",ptr2->info);
        }
      ptr2=ptr2->next;   //move to next node unconditionally.
      }
```

should do the job.

Also, as suggested by **@Gopi**, you can get rid of the redundant checks in your code. The *outer* `while` can check for not-NULL value of `ptr` whereas the *inner* `while` can check for not-NULL `ptr2`.

Comment: Well now its working but crashing after giving the correct output also could you tell me how you reached to this conclusion

Comment: @Gopi That should not cause any issue but yes, a good suggestion. I have updated my answer. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Also the logic will never check all the elements in the linked list as you are not moving the pointer `ptr` isn't it? Ok I think you meant the rest of the code stays as it is then that should be fine

Comment: @LEONARDO That may be from some other part of code. Can you use `gdb` and find out the exact offensive instruction.

Comment: @SouravGhosh- code is working and now not even crashing after changing the redundant checks although I don't how to use debugger..)

Comment: @LEONARDO On linmux, we use `gdb`. Some basic tutorials can be found [here](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ptr2=head1` line, with this line you are reassigning the `ptr2` to 1st value of `head1` again every time.

So every time same linked list node is getting compared.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
  while(ptr!=NULL)
  {
      ptr2 = head1;
      while(ptr2!=NULL)
      {
        if(ptr->info==ptr2->info)
        {
         printf("Common Elements are-%d\n",ptr2->info);
        }
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
      }
     ptr=ptr->next;
 }
```